# Modal Dialog Confirmation Box Text Disappears

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, modal-dialog

I wonder whether someone may be able to help me please.

I've put together [this](http://www.mapmyfinds.co.uk/development/testgallery.php) gallery page.

Using the icon under each image a user can delete any image they wish. Rather than deleting the image immediately, I'me trying to implement a Modal Confirmation Dialog box, so the user has the option to cancel the delete.

I can get the onlick event to work, but the text which asks the user whether they want to delete the image disappears from the dialog box when clicked.

I did have an issue with dialog box text appearing at the top of my page on page load. To overcome this I've used the following:

I have tried adding the following to prevent this:

```
.hide{   display: none !important;   }  

<div id="dialog-confirm" class="hide" title="Delete This Image?">
```

So I know that the issue is more than likely being caused by the this, but I'm not sure how to overcome both problems.

I just wondered whether someone may be able to look at this please and let me know where I've gone wrong.

Many thanks and regards

Comment: I can't find your `.hide` class anywhere in your css, was it added at all?

Comment: @AndresIlich, my apologies, this has now been added. Please also note the change in the error I'm encountering. Kind regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass the option `autoOpen: false` instead in your dialog call to hide it until it is called;

```
$( "#dialog-confirm" ).dialog({
    autoOpen: false
});
```

With this option in place, the dialog should be hidden from view until its called.

Also, you have placed the `.hide` class outside the `<style>..</style>` tags and its appearing on top of your page.

Comment: Hi @Andres LLich, thank you for taking the time to reply to my post and for the code solution. Kind regards

Answer (score 1):

u didn't mentioned your code, but i think problem is something like ,
your class "`.hide`" is getting apply properly, which contain "`display:none`".

but
you defined "`display:block`" property "**inline**", for  u r "dialog-confirm" box, in earlier code.

and
css attributes defined "**inline**" always have high priority than attributes defined in "**class**".

so `display:none` is gets overridden by "`display:block`".

try to give attribute at both location by "`.addClass()/.removeClass()`" or by "inline"
it might help u !!!  bcoz it worked for me in same kind of situation

i am also new to this field, so others please make me correct if i am wrong !!

Comment: my apologies, I've added the correct code to my page. Please also note a chnage to the problem I'm encountering. Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

Please Remove below style definition on the page. Then it will work:

```
.hide{   display: none !important;   }
```

You need to define the dialog box with option `autoOpen: false`  and need to invoke with open command on click of delete button(where you used `.live` code ). Please, Modify code as below:

```
  $( "#dialog-confirm" ).dialog({
                resizable: false,
                modal: true,
                autoOpen: false
                buttons: {
                    "Delete image": function() {
                    var img = $(this).closest(".galleria-image").find("img"); 
                            // send the AJAX request
                    $.ajax({
                    url : 'delete.php',
                    type : 'post',
                    data : { image : img.attr('src'),  userid: "VALUE", locationid: "VALUE"},
                    success : function(){
                    img.parent().fadeOut('slow');
                    }
                    });
                    },
                    Cancel: function() {
                        $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                    }
                }
            }); 

    $(".btn-delete").live("click", function(){      
        $( "#dialog-confirm" ).dialog( "open" );
    return false;
    });
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for taking the time to answer my post. I've amended the code , but unfortunately the text now appears at the top of the page on page load. Kind regards

Comment: Hi @Umesh, thank you for your continued with this, but please don't put yourself to anymore trouble as I now have a working solution. Kind regards